# Swipe Left/Right on collectionView not called while scrolling vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` with vertical scrolling, covering whole screen on the device (i.e fullscreen).

I have register the `Swipe Left and Right` gestures for my `collectionView`.

```
//------------right  swipe gestures in collectionView--------------//
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightSwiped))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    //-----------left swipe gestures in collectionView--------------//
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftSwiped))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

**Problem:**
Swipe left and right gestures callback does not fire while `collectionView` is scrolling vertically.

Is there any simple workaround for this.

here is my whole `ViewController` Class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {




@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self


    //------------right  swipe gestures in collectionView--------------//
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightSwiped))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    //-----------left swipe gestures in collectionView--------------//
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftSwiped))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.lable.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}

func rightSwiped()
{

    print("right swiped ")
}

func leftSwiped()
{

    print("left swiped ")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

here is my `collectionView` look like

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Solved, for solutions click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346679/swipe-left-right-on-collectionview-not-called-while-scrolling-vertically/38369367#38369367)

Comment: Solved.. Solutions is provided below as my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `delegate` of default gesture recognisers of the `UICollcetionView` is collection view object itself (obviously).

The default implementation of `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`returns `YES`in side the UICollectionView class.

So to address your problem ,you need to set the collection view object as delegate to your "left" and "right" swipe gesture recognisers as follows.

```
swipeRight.delegate = collectionView;
swipeLeft.delegate = collectionView;
```

This should make your `rightSwiped()` and `leftSwiped()` to get fired when corresponding swipe occurs.

Comment: Emmm, Sorry I am not getting this. Should I have to make custom UIcollectionView to do this?

Comment: thanks for pointing me shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer. I have done it :)
Will post my solution soon

Comment: Great .Thanks for accepting my answer :). I thought to mention about subclassing UICollectionView if you need additional behaviour.However your current scope of requirement (just making gestures work) doesn't require subclassing.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Hariprasad for pointing me `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`

Here is the solution

I have subclass the `UICollectionView` and implemented the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` like below

```
import UIKit

class TouchCollectionView: UICollectionView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let gesture = UIGestureRecognizer()
    gesture.delegate = self // Set Gesture delegate so that shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer can be set to true on initialzing the UICollectionView
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}   
}
```

- change the class property of your collectionView from identity inspector
  http://prntscr.com/bsqbq3

Whole ViewController will remain the same as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is very simple Solution

1)You need take a property to store previous content offset

2)Implement the delegate method `ScrollViewDidScroll` & compare current content Offset with previous content Offset

```
var contentOffset: CGFloat = 0
```

**// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   if contentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
   // scrolling up
   } else if contentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
   //scrolling Down
   }
    contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

3)It can be done without adding any gesture recognizer.

Comment: I am scrolling vertically. not horizontally.
this is valid for horizontal scroll

Comment: yes I am scrolling vertically with up/down gesture but while scrolling my swipe Left/Right not fired. thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code it may helps you.**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.lable.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftSwiped))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightSwiped))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
This help me.

```
class OnboardingVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
@IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
            
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSwipeAction))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        leftSwipe.delegate = self
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
     }
            
     func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
     }
            
     @objc private func leftSwipeAction() {
     print("Left Swipe")
     }
}
```