# How to call map annotation when collection view swipe in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

In my project, i am using MK map and uicollection view. In map view showing nearest user friends location map annotation based on user current location. In collection view same as user friends location name and distance are showed in UICollection view. (Note: For collection i have used UPCarouselFlowLayout cocopod library)

Here i want to do highlight the map annotation marker of very nearest to user current location and wile swiping collection map annotation should be call out and selected in map.

Here is the code which i have tried for nearest user friend location and collection view:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        pin.image = UIImage(named: "carIcon")
        userPinView = pin
        return pin

    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    }
    else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    print("Get parking array count",parkingTypeArray.count)
    if parkingTypeArray.count > 0 {

        print("parking ty \(parkingTypeArray)")
        //

        for cameraa in parkingTypeArray.enumerated() {

            if cameraa.element == "Free" {

                let pinImage = UIImage(named: "free")
                annotationView!.image = pinImage

            }else if cameraa.element == "Paid" {

                let pinImage = UIImage(named: "paid")
                annotationView!.image = pinImage

            }
        }
    }

    return annotationView
  }
```

Here the code for collection view :

```
     //UICollection view - Location for parking car and street name
     extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cameraDetails.count
    }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

         let cell = nearestCurrentLocationCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! nearestLocationCollectionViewCell

    if self.cameraImageArray.count > 0 {

        cell.locationImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 
      self.cameraImageArray[indexPath.row]))
        print("get location image",URL(string: 
        self.cameraImageArray[indexPath.row]))
    }

    if self.cameraDetails.count > 0 {

        cell.locationName.text = self.cameraDetails[indexPath.row]

    }
     //            cell.locationDistance.text = locationDistance[indexPath.row]

     if distanceArray.count > 0 {

        cell.locationDistance.text = String(format: " Distance : %.2f ", distanceArray[indexPath.row]/1000)

    }

      //            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
      //            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true

        return cell
    }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     moveMapPage()
       }

     fileprivate var pageSize: CGSize {
    let layout = self.nearestCurrentLocationCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
    var pageSize = layout.itemSize
    if layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal {
        pageSize.width += layout.minimumLineSpacing
    } else {
        pageSize.height += layout.minimumLineSpacing
    }
    return pageSize
    }

   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let layout = nearestCurrentLocationCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
    let pageSide = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? self.pageSize.width : self.pageSize.height
    let offset = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? scrollView.contentOffset.x : scrollView.contentOffset.y
    currentPage = Int(floor((offset - pageSide / 2) / pageSide) + 1)
    print("currentpage::::\(self.currentPage)")


        if let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations.first {
            // Ignore if correspondent annotation is already selected
            if 
   selectedAnnotation.isEqual(self.mapView.annotations[currentPage]) {

    self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[currentPage], animated: true)
            }
        }


   }


 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any other Information of annotation like the title or anything else 
Except for the current page?

Comment: nope .. I did not get any error. Is above correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Try like this it's working for me**

`UICollectionView` **Delegate Method**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    for annotations_item in mapView.annotations{

       if annotations_item.title == Arr_Map_Data[indexPath.row].Title{
                 self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotations_item, animated: true)
       }

    }
}
```

**MapView Delegate Method**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    // first ensure that it really is an EventAnnotation:
    // Note :- Here get your Annotation I used MyPointAnnotation custom class that's why use that

    if let eventAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyPointAnnotation {

            if let index = self.Arr_Map_Comparables.index(of: eventAnnotation.obj!){
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
                collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PvDev from where you want to selectAnnotation animation I have to do it on did selected method.

Comment: whether this will work on collection view while swiping cells.

Comment: For Collection view Swipe Gesture Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369367/10150796

Comment: sorry not collection swipe. while scroll collection view selected index should select map annotation

Comment: @PvDev You want Display Map annotation selected on selected collection view cell and scroll to collection view cell for selected map annotation right?

Comment: exactly.. sorry fr my bad english

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177849/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-pvdev).